# Is it possible to capture real-time microphone in Lua?

Tags: audio, lua

The title is self-explanatory. Is there a way to capture a microphone in real time using Lua?

Comment: This is OS-dependent.  Can you load external C libraries in Lua (with `require`)?

Comment: I'm using a Linux Mint Cinammom 20.04. I believe that I can load C libraries with require

Comment: What Lua should do with captured microphone?  Treat input as sequence of signed integer values and do some processing?  Or redirect the audio stream to some destination?